# Laravel Downloading multiple files using .zip

Tags: laravel, zip

I'm having some problem when I try to download files using .zip

```
use ZipArchive;
.
.
.

public function donwload(){
    $zip      = new ZipArchive;
    $fileName = 'documents.zip';
    if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {          
      foreach ( Documents::all() as  $document) {     
        $zip->addFile( public_path('uploads/documents/'.$document->filename) , $document->filename);
      }
      $zip->close();
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
}
```

I'm having this error:

```
ZipArchive::addFile(): No such file or directory
```

Comment: That error is saying that one of your iterations of `public_path('uploads/documents/'.$document->filename)` does not exist; you'll need to debug and figure out _why_.

Comment: I encountered similar issues then I started using Storage facade for file path:   Storage::path('path') instead of public_path('path')

Answer (score 0):

the solution is add this condition before `$zip->addFile()`

```
public function donwload(){
    $zip      = new ZipArchive;
    $fileName = 'documents.zip';
    if ($zip->open(public_path($fileName), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {          
      foreach ( Documents::all() as  $document) {    
       if( file_exists(public_path("uploads/documents/".$document->filename)) ){ 
        $zip->addFile( public_path('uploads/documents/'.$document->filename) , $document->filename);
       }
      }
      $zip->close();
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
}
```

this error happens when one file don't exist on directory.